# Getting undefined error after successfull value output in browser

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

This is my first angular-node application and I'm getting an error when printing the value I'm getting from an **getQuestion** method of **qa.service.ts**.The **getQuestion** is fetching a data from backend by using question id.
[image]

I'm getting question from backend and when I try to print that value in my browser I'm getting an undefined error but value as well in browser.

**qa.service.ts**

```
getQuestion(index){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/questions/'+index).map(
        res => {
            const question = res.json().question[0];
            let votesUp = question.votes.map(vote => vote.dir == "up");
            let votesDown = question.votes.map(vote => vote.dir == "down");
            let votes = votesUp.length-votesDown.length;
            return new Questions(question._id,question.title,question.description,question.author,votes,question.date,question.answers);           
        }
    );
}
```

**question-details.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
       this.QA.getQuestion(this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe(
           ques => {
               this.question = ques;
               console.log(this.question);
           }
       );
    }
```

**question-detail.component.html**

```
<div class="section_detail">
    <div class="section_detail--info">
        <h2>{{question.author.fullname}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong here and Why I'm getting error as well as value in browser ?

Comment: Code not picture please, & snippetify if possible :)

Comment: @admcfajn I removed the all code pictures and replaced it with snippets.

Comment: hi, can you share the total question-details.component.ts

Comment: I’m confused, you’re seeing the value in the console log but you’re getting an undefined error when you try to render to the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my reading of the question is correct, you’re seeing the value output to your console log but getting a null refernce error in your log as well. The reason for this is because in your template, you’re accessing a variable that isn’t defined until the service gets the value from your api. In your detail component ts file, the variable question is undefined until the api returns, but the html template tries to access its properties as soon as the view is initialized, so it is trying to access properties of an undefined reference, hence the error. To fix this, you just need to put a null guard in your template which is quite easy with angulars Elvis operator:

```
<h2>{{ question?.author?.fullname }}</h2>
```

Those question marks after each item tell angular to just stop trying if the reference is “falsey”, which null and undefined both are. This will result in nothing displaying in its place, as though it were an empty string, until the value is set by the service. If you want a loading value or something else, there are several ways to achieve that using ngIf

Comment: Thanks! It works but is there is any way to make template rendering wait when fetching data from api.

Comment: you can use ngIf instead like <div class="section_detail" *ngIf="question"> to hide everything till it's loaded, or you could use a resolve block in your router to force the data to be resolved before the template is even initialized, in either case you'll probably still want some kind of "loading" indicator.